# Repartitioning /data partition

Tags: internal-storage, partitions

For a project requirement I am trying to resize the memory partition on userdata (/data filesystem) to create a new file system. I am using parted on the device. When I tried to use resize command in parted mode for /data memory block, I am unable to do so because it is used by default in the device.

Error obtained :
Error: Partition /dev/block/mmcblk0p4 is being used. You must unmount it before
you modify it with Parted.

As this is /data folder I am unable to unmount it. When I tried to unmount I am getting following error.

umount /data
failed: Device or resource busy

I tried killing all the processes using this folder using lsof command. However, this contains all apps data so killing all those processes reboots device.

Can somebody help me ways to resize these partition? I need commands only through adb as I am trying to create an automatic script for this.

Comment: You can only resize it in recovery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to modify *any* partition, **reboot into a custom recovery**.

Most partitions are in use whenever a normal system is running. You can't play around with them unless you are in an alternative system, like recovery.

BTW, almost anything that runs OK in Android also runs well in recovery, so simply go ahead.

---

Can you resize `C:\` in Windows without rebooting?

Comment: I am not able to get into recovery mode using adb reboot recovery.

Comment: Reboot to bootloader then flash a new one with `fastboot`.